React-Native 0.73 absolute path not working
Following the update to React Native version 0.73.4, I encountered an issue where absolute imports ceased to function correctly. There appear to be two primary solutions to this problem: the first involves utilizing Yarn workspaces, while the second requires an update to the metro.config.js file, specifically by activating the enableGlobalPackages option within the resolver configuration, as shown below:
const config = {
  resolver: {
    enableGlobalPackages: true,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}

Although I would prefer to resolve this issue by enabling global packages, this method does not seem to be effective. Notably, the problem arises when executing the react-native bundle command, whereas building the full artifact does not trigger the same issue.

